# SQL server stored procedure - Can I invert this query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am not an sql Guru, that's why I'm asking you guys.

I have this stored procedure:

```
USE [groep2_festivals]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetGroupsNotOfFestival]    Script Date: 15-05-13 10:03:17 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Robbie Vercammen
-- Create date: 2013-05-15
-- Description: Getting all groups not on a defined festival
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGroupsNotOfFestival]
    @festId  nvarchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT b.*, p.* 
    FROM bands b 
    JOIN bandsperfestival bpf ON b.band_id = bpf.band_id 
    JOIN podia p ON p.pod_id = bpf.pod_id
    WHERE bpf.fest_id != @festId
END
```

And these tables,
Bands:

[image: bands table]

Podia (Stages in english):

[image: Stages table]

BandsPerFestival holding all bands that perform on festivals:

[image: table with all bands performing on a festival]

I used this stored procedure to get all bands performing on a specific festival (by festival id) and that works, but I would like to invert this but simple replacing `WHERE bpf.fest_id = @festId` with `WHERE bpf.fest_id != @festId` doesn't seem to work. I get the same list but the bands that actually do perform on a festival are returned twice.

Example:

[image: example of what's wrong]

As you can see, nickelback appears in the list twice when they are actually performing on the chosen festival.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I should have said this earlier, but I want all the bands that are not performing on a specific festival,

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you question. If you replace `!=` by `=`, don't the results change?

Comment: Yes I do get a different result, but as bands also perform on other festivals, they will also be included in the result. fe. if nickelback performs on festival with id 2, it will also be included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a left outer join, and then forced the right side of the join to be null.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
FROM bands b 
left outer JOIN bandsperfestival bpf ON b.band_id = bpf.band_id 
and @festId = bpf.fest_id
where bpf.fest_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explain what you mean when you say "Invert" this.  Do you mean you want all bands that did NOT play any festival?  Or All bands that did not play a specific festival?

Comment: I want all bands that are not performing on a specific festival, sorry for that